# Get DisplayAttribute attribute from PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, data-annotations, propertyinfo

```
class SomeModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Quantity Required")]
    public int Qty { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cost per Item")]
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to map the model into a list of `{ PropertyName, DisplayName }` pairs, but I've got stuck.

```
var properties 
    = typeof(SomeModel)
        .GetProperties()
        .Select(p => new 
            {
                p.Name,
                p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute),
                              false).Single().ToString()
            }
        );
```

The above doesn't compile and I'm not sure it's the right approach anyway, but hopefully you can see the intent. Any pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In this case you need to define specific property names for anonymous type.

```
var properties = typeof(SomeModel).GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false))
    .Select(p => new
        {
            PropertyName = p.Name,
            DisplayName = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute),
                false).Cast<DisplayAttribute>().Single().Name
        });
```